# Running build through jenkins cannot find oracle jdbc jar which is in my local repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have successfully installed the **Oracle jdbc jar** into my local repo.  I'm also able to run `mvn compile` successfully from command line.  But, when I try to build using `Jenkins`, it throws this error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/myproject/src/main/java/com/company/util/myclass.java:[10,24] package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist
```

Again, running `mvn compile` works.  It's when running through `jenkins` that I get this error.

Comment: In jenkins you can specify project local repos which are different from your local user repo.

Comment: Correct. More than likely when you run the build from command-line it's using a different Maven settings file (Is Jenkins running as the user "me" or "jenkins". The latter will have a different homedir) Try running Maven with the "-s" option. Better still install the Configuration Files plugin to manage your Maven settings files.

Comment: I'm running Jenkins are anonymous user, no credential setup.  I'm running "java -jar jenkins.war".  I installed the Config plug in.  Pointed my project to use my local repo.  Still getting the same probem.  This what I see on the console output.  Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\myid\.jenkins\workspace\myproject\pom.xml -s C:\Users\myid\.m2\settings.xml -gs C:\Users\myid\.m2\settings.xml install
.../C:/Users/myid/.jenkins/workspace/myproject/src/main/java/com/mycompany/util/MyClass.java:[10,24] package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist

Comment: I have a workaround for this.  Instead of creating a maven 2/3 project.  I created a "Build a free-style software project" with command line to "mvn".  Still would like to know how to  resolve the problem.  Thanks.